# how to redirect www to http with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, server

I have a node web app running on a server. I'm running the app with pm2 and the app runs on localhost:3000. I have my nginx config file located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` set up like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;



    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {

            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


}
```

The site works when I go to http://example.com but when I go to www.example.com the browser says Failed to open page, can't find server.

How do I get the nginx config (or something else) to redirect www requests to just http?

Comment: What's the actual error message?, as the one you have mentioned sounds like you have not setup DNS correctly

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the actual message is "Safari Can't find server"

Answer (score 0):

Don´t you have to put the server_name, like this:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com
```

Comment: `_` is the default, ie all thats not matched